# How to refresh the table data when one of the item has its valid till date and time has expired in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, momentjs

I have a table data where there are section called **Item**, **Time** and **ValidTill**
so for example one of the **Item** has a **time** of **April 2nd 2022, 3:08:01 pm** and is **ValidTill** time of  **April 2nd 2022, 3:09:26 pm** so after this validtill expires i have make an api call in useEffect which i am already doing it once the component mounts but i also want it to run when **validTill** expires so how can it be achieved

```
const [quotesData, setQuotesData] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  getRandomdata();
}, []);
async function getRandomdata() {
  const result = await RandomApi.get(`/quotes/${symbolId}`);
  setQuotesData(result.data.payload);
}
```

```
    <Table stickyHeader className={classes.stickyHeader}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Item</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Time</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Validtill</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {quotesData.map(({Item, time, valid_till }) => (
          <TableRow key={Item}>
            <TableCell>{Item}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              {moment(time).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              {moment(valid_till).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used another approach, instead of running an interval polling for each item, which would be greedy, I think you could just calculate the time left from the moment the component is mounted to the expiry time and just place a timeout with the difference between those two dates, I made an example here, see if it can help you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t5jfab

I placed just one item in the array, but it works with any amount of items, since it just cycles through them and places timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

As there could be many rows in your table and you would like to listen to each row's expiry event so that you can send an API request for each specific row right??.

To achieve it you can use `setInterval` javascript function to set interval for each second and in the body of setInterval callback you can check for each rows expiry like this.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
    // loop on each row an compare time to current time for expiration check if expired send the api request
        

    quotesData.map(({ Item, time, valid_till }) => {
      if (valid_till > currentTime) {
        // expired
        //send api request
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

this could be a good solution if your dataset is not too large. For larger datasets we have to do some more tweaks on the code.

Comment: ok,so this currentTime variable in if condition i can get this using moment ? and when to clearInterval ?

Comment: yes, you can get current time by calling moment() to compare time. And you can clear the interval after you navigate away for this page, so clear it in the use effect hook.

Comment: i should run this useEffect when mounted and also when validTill expires so can i remove the empty array dependency ?

Comment: the array dependency should be empty because after mount the interval will start and in the interval, you are checking for expiry.